# Convert yii resolveNameID() method into Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-extension

I am Trying to Convert [Yii  Jui timepicker extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/jtimepicker/) into Yii2. But i am stacked at one method which is available in Yii but not in Yii2 called `resolveNameID()`. I Found that method at [CinputWidget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CInputWidget#resolveNameID-detail).

But this method not found in [yii2-jui/InputWidget](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui).

I am able to convert below method in Yii2 partially but don't know where to put them. May be in `yii2-jui/InputWidget.php`

`resolveNameID()` in Yii:

```
protected function resolveNameID()
{
   if($this->name!==null)
      $name=$this->name;
   elseif(isset($this->htmlOptions['name']))
      $name=$this->htmlOptions['name'];
   elseif($this->hasModel())
      $name=CHtml::activeName($this->model,$this->attribute);
   else
      throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','{class} must specify "model" and "attribute" or "name" property values.',array('{class}'=>get_class($this))));

   if(($id=$this->getId(false))===null)
   {
      if(isset($this->htmlOptions['id']))
          $id=$this->htmlOptions['id'];
      else
          $id=CHtml::getIdByName($name);
  }

    return array($name,$id);
  }
```

I want to convert above method into Yii2 or any alternate method for `resolveNameID()` in Yii2.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why wont you use already existing and working extension: [timepicker](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-timepicker/) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at this doc for [base helper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html)

in detail look at  `getInputId()`

> Generates an appropriate input ID for the specified attribute name or
>   expression.

and `getInputName()`

> Generates an appropriate input name for the specified attribute name
>   or expression.

Comment: Thanks.  @scaisEdge. I will try.